# How to lock screen orientation

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Is there a way how to lock the screen orientation but still be able to listen for device orientation changes? My UI consists of an `ImageView` and few `buttons` at the bottom. The application screen orientation should be locked but the images on the buttons should change when the device orientation changes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what ? "The application screen orientation should be locked but the images on the buttons should change when the device orientation changes." So you want it to change or not ? explain more please

Comment: Imagine that there are some pictures on the buttons that are meant to be read in portrait view, if the user decides to tilt the device, it would look bad with these images on buttons if they remained in the same orientation. So I want to just tilt the pictures on the buttons according to the orientation.

Comment: Will you let android destroy the activity? Or you can just override onCOnfigurationChange (people say that's bad practice).

Comment: Have you considered adding another layout for landscape instead? This will probably save you time and heartache.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way. In the AndroidManifest.xml, where your activity is declared, you need to add another property [configChanges](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges) as following.

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity" 
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
```

This means your activity will handle orientation and currently available size changes by itself. Then you have to override [onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) method in your Activity and change images there.

Comment: OnConfigurationChanged is never called in that activity. I guess, this can distinguish just between ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE and ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT so it will not solve my problem. Anyway, any idea why it is not called?

Comment: Have you added configChanges to AndroidManifest?

Comment: Yes I did. Anyway, I solved this problem is other way, but thanks for suggestions.